# TROPOMI NO2 and SO2 too small ... being approximated to zero

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

I am trying to download TROPOMI NO2 and SO2 data for my region as a timeseries from Google Earth Engine, however, the values are small (see attached images) and as such, when I download the CSV file, I find that all the values have been reduced to zero (0).

How can I solve this in order to download the values as they are?

[image]

Here is my code: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/42ee21db931d153e837e050e65314ab2)

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[27.671093749999986, 5.861609095403631],
  [27.671093749999986, -12.999528581977067],
  [44.19453124999998, -12.999528581977067],
  [44.19453124999998, 5.861609095403631]]], null, false);

var data = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2')
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-30');

var tmseries = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: data,
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
});
print(tmseries);

print(tmseries.getDataTable());
```